# Validation for special characters not working

Tags: javascript, validation

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
function isSpclChar() {

    var iChars = "!@#$%^&*()+=-[]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?";
    if (document.getElementById('edit_tagline').value.indexOf(iChars) != -1) {
        alert("The box has special characters. ");
    } else {
        alert("No special character");
    }
}
</script>
<body>

   <input type="text" id="edit_tagline" onblur="isSpclChar()">

</body>
</html>
```

**My first question why this validation is not working?**

**My second question is can anybody explain me the meaning of this line**

```
if(document.getElementById('edit_tagline').value.indexOf(iChars) != -1)
```

because I am new to JavaScript and copy paste the code from somewhere I don't know it's working.

So kindly if anyone could explain me the working of this code?

Comment: iChars is't a character range, it's treating it as a single word. You're going to need to implement a regular expression in order to do this.

Comment: @remus can you tell me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iChars is't a character range, it's treating it as a single word. You're going to need to implement a regular expression in order to do this.

Here's a working example of some validation in javascript, leveraging jQuery for brevity. Hopefully you can get it working in your context. I took the liberty of using alphabet characters and negating the expression, vs. writing out all of the potential special characters (there are hundreds including unicode ranges!).

```
$('button').click(function () {
    if (!(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/i).test($('#edit_tagline').val())) {
        alert("The box has special characters. ");
    } else {
        alert("No special character");
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="edit_tagline">
<button>Test</button>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/remus/9jwGW/

If you're not familiar with regular expressions, best read up on how those work (and check out http://regex101.com) before you get much further.

Comment: I wanted javascript validation if you could help me on that please.

Comment: The regular expression and code contained within *is* javascript, I just wrapped it in jQuery in order to demonstrate it to you. See [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: And you'd use `document.getElementById('edit_tagline').value` instead of `$('#edit_tagline').val()`.

Comment: the code is working great and the best thing is it is working for all the special characters in the keyboard.Thanks man just one last question how `!(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/i)` this is checking all the special chracters in keyboard.I just need to understand this line.

Comment: there is one problem in this code if user enters say George Smith so the space between george and smith is calculated as special character so is there any validation in this code to ignore the space between two words.

Comment: Crash course in regular expressions: javascript requires delimieters when declaring one. Hence the `/ ..... /`. The `i` afterwards denotes a special flag, in this case case-insensitive. `[]` denote a character class: a set of characters or character ranges. If you need a space, include it in the character class like `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]` instead `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. Also regex101 is your friend.